# Select All Columns From Table With 1 Distinct Column and a Where Condition

Tags: sql

This had been asked multiple times, but I am not finding a solution that works for me. I have a view similar to below. I need to run a query that returns all of the columns, but only once for any unique GLASS_ID. I also need a where clause **WHERE GLASS_ID LIKE '%' + @PartialGlassId + '%'**

```
VEH_ID   GLASS_ID   OPENING_SEQ  PART_NUM  PREFIX_CD ANT_FLAG  BLK_SIZE1
26975     DB00201        1          201       DB        Y        14.00
26864     DB00375        1          375       DB        N        16.00
26865     DB00375        1          375       DB        N        16.00
26866     DB00375        1          375       DB        N        16.00
38929     DB00408        1          408       DB        N        12.00
38930     DB00408        1          408       DB        N        12.00
38931     DB00408        1          408       DB        N        12.00
38932     DB00408        1          408       DB        N        12.00
38933     DB00408        1          408       DB        N        12.00
38990     DB00408        1          408       DB        N        12.00
38991     DW01015        1         1015       DB        N        12.00
```

The results should be

```
VEH_ID  NAGS_GLASS_ID OPENING_SEQ PART_NUM PREFIX_CD ANT_FLAG BLK_SIZE1
26975     DB00201        1          201       DB        Y        14.00
26864     DB00375        1          375       DB        N        16.00
38929     DB00408        1          408       DB        N        12.00
```

for WHERE GLASS_ID LIKE '%DB00%'

Comment: which `rdbms` are you using? and please saw us your work (`sql`)

Comment: It appears the duplication is a function of the Veh_Id... So what VEH_ID do you want returned? or eliminate that column from the query and you'd be fine. your options include: return them all by concatenating them together, getting the average, getting the lowest value (Min), getting the maximum value getting a count of them.  But what you can't do is get only one row with all existing veh_IDs because  glass ID  exists in multiple vehicles.

Comment: The VEH_ID is required because I'm using C# entities and the generator I use would not return an entity object unless the resulting query fields precisely match the view structure. The results are displayed in a grid where the user chooses to drill down further into a specific Glass Id where all vehicle are displayed. There are also other columns not shown here that contain identical and displayed information and are shown to the user to help their selection, but not important to the basic question.

Comment: To simplify: in your example veh_ID is 26864... Why'd you pick that one? and 38929 for DB00408?

Comment: @xQbert purely arbitrary - could have been 26866, or 2. The user doesn't see vehicle ids at the top level because this search is on the glass id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT b.* 
FROM yourTable b
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT MIN(VEH_ID) as minV,  GLASS_ID as g
   FROM yourTable
   GROUP BY GLASS_ID) as d
  ON b.Glass_ID = d.g and b.VEH_ID = d.minV
WHERE b.GLASS_ID LIKE  '%DB00%'
```

NOTE : the WHERE clause, in this case, could be in the subquery from the INNER JOIN also.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select distinct max(veh_ID), glass_ID, Opening_SEQ, part_Num, PRefix_CD, Ant_Flag, BLK_Size1
FROM yourTable
WHERE GLASS_ID LIKE '%' + @PartialGlassId + '%'
Group by glass_ID, Opening_SEQ, part_Num, PRefix_CD, Ant_Flag, BLK_Size1
```

other option

```
Select distinct group_Concat(veh_ID, ', '), glass_ID, Opening_SEQ, part_Num, PRefix_CD, Ant_Flag, BLK_Size1
FROM yourTable
WHERE GLASS_ID LIKE '%' + @PartialGlassId + '%'
Group by glass_ID, Opening_SEQ, part_Num, PRefix_CD, Ant_Flag, BLK_Size1
```